# How to take down a bookdown page?

Tags: r, bookdown, rstudio-connect

I've accidentally created two bookdown instances:

- https://bookdown.org/stanfordgsbsilab/tutorial/
- https://bookdown.org/stanfordgsbsilab/ml-ci-tutorial/

Going forward I'd like to deprecate the first and keep only the latter. How can I take it down? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to be connected to bookdown, via Rstudio Connect.
2. Then open your document.
3. In the upper right corner, click on the icon with "..." surrounded by a circle => then choose 'delete'